# How to get the string in last parenthesis?

Tags: python, regex

I would like to get the string inside a pair of parenthesis.

For example, my string is `Here is my string (This is the string in parenthesis (and this is the second layer))`.

I want to get `This is the string in parenthesis (and this is the second layer))`

I tried to use `(?<=\()(.*?)(?=\))` and I got`['and this is the second layer']`.

What is the correct approach?

Thanks.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you want `This is the string in parenthesis (and this is the second layer)` without the additional parenthesis in the end, yes?

Comment: yes, you are correct.

Comment: Well, the question was closed due to being a duplicate, but I'm not sure the other answers work well for your situation.
You can do:
`s.split("(", 1)[1].rsplit(")", 1)[0]`